# How to check variable type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JS object of type any and i want to check its content and get value in correct type so i imagined a function like this

```
function getRequiredField<T>(config: any, name: string): T {
    if (config[name] === undefined) throw new Error(`Required field ${name} is missing`);
    return config[name] as T;
}
```

And its working as i want, but now i would like to check the typeof config[name] and be sure it is the same as T. How can i do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `T` is a type and types are removed at compile time. You can't use `T` at runtime as a value

Comment: Yes @AlekseyL. I know i can't use T with `instance of`, and i can't use `typeof`neither. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

Comment: Where config is coming from? I guess you're looking for some kind of json schema validator

Comment: @AlekseyL. that is exactly what i want to do, config is a json object loaded via `config = required('myfile.json');`

Comment: Well there're a lot of options https://blog.logrocket.com/dynamic-type-validation-in-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [instanceof](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#4.19.4) operator to check if it's type instance of `T` or not.

```
config[name] instanceof Sprite;
```

This will return `Boolean` primary type value.

Comment: no, you can't because `T` is not a value and doesn't exist at runtime